# Python salt cloudclient is not logging anything

Tags: python, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I am trying to create new nodes using the CloudClient in saltstack python API. Nodes are created successfully but I don't see any logging happening. Below is the code which I am using.

```
from salt.cloud import CloudClient
cloud_client = CloudClient() 
kwargs = {'parallel': True}
cloud_client.map_run(path="mymap.map",**kwargs)
```

Is there way to run the same code in debug mode to see the output on console from this python script if logging cannot be done.

### logging parameters in cloud

```
log_level: all
log_level_logfile:  all
log_file: /var/logs/salt.log
```

When I try to run with sal-cloud on cli it is working with the below command:

```
salt-cloud -m mymap.map -P
```

Comment: Did you try to setup the console logger as mentioned in *your* issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/43482 ?

Comment: @florianb Yes I did. Its working now after adding the below code. `from salt.log.setup import setup_console_logger`
        `setup_console_logger(log_level='debug')`

Comment: Ah okay, i'd suggest you answering your question yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able make it work by adding the below code

```
from salt.log.setup import setup_console_logger 
setup_console_logger(log_level='debug')
```